# How do I use Glimpse to find out what is causing my ASP.NET MVC application to hang?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, firefox, diagnostics

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that makes pretty heavy use of javascript and JQuery for both administrative functions as well as customer-facing functions.  Recently I reorganized the administrative screens to be able to more cleanly fit administrative controls for some new features.

I tested using IE and Chrome and found that there was a slight, but acceptable hang in one of the busier pages.  However, the main person who uses the admin pages uses Firefox and kept reporting an unacceptable hang.  I finally checked it out and found that what hangs in Chrome and IE for 2-3 seconds hangs in Firefox for 10-12 seconds, which is no good.

Not knowing where to turn, I wound up installing Glimpse and got it configured and running just fine, but I'm still having trouble figuring out how to drill into it to find out what area of the page is causing trouble.  All I can tell so far is that it is definitely something with how the client (Firefox) is rendering.  To be clear, it happens on all browsers, but for some reason it is way more pronounced in Firefox.

Can someone please give me some pointers on how to get started on diagnosing the issue?  I'm not married to the idea of using Glimpse, but it seems like a pretty decent tool from what I can tell.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you're describing, the problem appears to be client side. With that said, Glimpse may not be as well-suited as using Firefox's own profiler.

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> will bring up the web developer performance screen. From there, you can begin/end a performance analysis and gain more insight into what may be taking longer than expected.

It may also be worthwhile to look at the network tab and make sure assets are loading in a timely manner.

Keep in mind as well that add-ins could play into the latency. If the end-user has a setup that performs post-page processing (such as Greasemonkey scripts or (recalling an earlier add-in) a Skype plugin that used to transform phone numbers on the page to direct-dial links), that would also play a part in the performance. A good way to rule these out is to hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while starting up Firefox (effectively running it in [Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)), which would determine if it's Firefox itself or an add-in that's to blame.